# can't loop out data from json array?

Tags: json

I can't loop data out from response array.

```
$.post(myurl , function(response){
      for (var i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
         alert(response.result[i]);
      }
},"json");
```

result of returned json array is :

```
{"result":["data one","data two","data three"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did u try using JSON.parse to obtain your data in the JSON object format?
2. Always use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to see if your JSON is proper, before using JSON.parse.

**EDIT** : In your head tag add json2.js. Go [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and download it.
Then whenever u have a json string like the one in your question. Just use `JSON.parse(somejsonstring);`

```
var t = '{"result":["data one","data two","data three"]}' ; //Response Text
var p = JSON.parse(t); //p.result[0] will give u "data one"
```

Comment: How should I use JSON.parse? Could u plz write it for sample?

Comment: var t = '{"result":["data one","data two","data three"]}' ; //Response Text
var p = JSON.parse(t); //p.result[0] will give u "data one"

ya .. it works great.Thz K.A.G

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an object's properties with a for each loop:

```
for (var prop in response) {
  alert(prop + ": " + response[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. Misread your question at first. What you have looks like it should work, as long as the json response is as you've shown. Can you link to a live example?

Comment: This answered the question I wanted, basically I was getting undefined errors on a json response using for loop.  Likely some data was not converted into an object.